# What is the purpose of sll and add in the translated MIPS code?

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, mips, memory-address

I was reading some MIPS notes regarding translating C statement to MIPS.

C code of swap function below:

```
swap ( int v[], int k) {
    int temp;
    temp = v[k];
    v[k] = v[k + 1];
    v[k + 1] = temp;
}
```

I was told that k maps to $5, base address of v[ ] is mapped to $4 and temp is mapped to  $15.
The swap function takes in the arguments k = 3 and assume that base address of v is 2000.

Simplified MIPS version below:

```
swap:

    sll $2, $5, 2
    add $2, $4, $2
    lw  $15, 0($2)
    lw  $16, 4($2)
    sw  $16, 0($2)
    sw  $15, 4($2)
```

The confusion here is why is there *sll* and *add* in the translated MIPS?

Comment: That asm is basically what clang does.  https://godbolt.org/z/rMM994.  GCC is dumber and fails to take advantage of the offset part of the `lw` / `sw` addressing mode, instead using 2 extra instructions: `addiu` and `addu` to calculate `v + k+1` separately from `v+k`.  Re: register names: http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html the args are of course in $a0 and $a1 ($4 and $5).  $2 is $v0 in the standard calling convention; the return value or a scratch reg.  $15 is $t7.  But $16 is $s0, which functions should save/restore if they want to use it (call-preserved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from being [byte addressable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing), as most modern machines are.

Byte addressing means that the processor can access each individual byte of memory — in such a system, incrementing a valid byte address value by 1 means referring to the next sequential byte of memory.

Words, used by the `int` datatype, are 32-bits wide, so require 4 bytes of memory.  Thus, `a[0]` occupies bytes `addr+0`, `addr+1`, `addr+2`, and `addr+3`, where `addr` is a byte address of `a`.  `a[1]` is offset from `a[0]` by 4 bytes, at `addr+4`!

C knows that the elements of "arrays of `int`" require 4 bytes each so 4 bytes separation, and thus it knows that `a+i` under the hood means `a + i * 4`, which will refer to 4 consecutive addresses for each element of the array, starting at `i*4`, which leaves room for all the lower elements.

The computation `i * 4` is sometimes called "scaling".  Whereas in C we can refer to the index position directly `a[i]`, in assembly we have to scale the index explicitly.

The `sll` is an efficient way to multiply by 4 — the constant 2 in the `sll` means 2 digits to the left (aka: * 100<sub>2</sub>, i.e. * 100 in binary).

The add sums the array base with the scaled index to make the actual address of the desired word for the array reference.

We can also see the generated code using constants 0 or 4.  Because these constants are also scaled, the 4 refers to the next element of the array beyond what was computed.   Which is to say that if `0($2)` refers to `a[k]` then `4($2)` refers to `a[k+1]`.